# For loop not stopping and random generated number not being saved (number guessing game)

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm doing a number guessing game in an Android app. You have three tries to guess the number. If you run out of trials, then you loose.

I added a `for` loop so that each time the user inputs then it adds one more. But, when I run the app and I input the numbers more than three times, it doesn't show the "You don't have more tries" message, like it's not counting the tries.

I've tried changing the `for` to a restart button, and then every time I click the restart button it adds one more. But, that didn't work either.

My current code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int trials;
    private int maxTrials = 3;
    private TextView s_title, t_rules, strt_title, t_introgss;
    private Button btn_start;
    private EditText num_input;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    num_input = findViewById(R.id.num_input);
    btn_start = findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    s_title = findViewById(R.id.s_title);
    t_rules = findViewById(R.id.t_rules);
    strt_title = findViewById(R.id.strt_title);
    t_introgss = findViewById(R.id.t_introgss);

    btn_start.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0){

            s_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            t_rules.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btn_start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            strt_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t_introgss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            num_input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });



    num_input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(num_input.getText().toString());
            int number = 1 + (int) (30 * Math.random());

            for (trials = 0; trials < maxTrials; trials++) {
                if (guessNum == number) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (guessNum < number && trials != maxTrials - 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The number is bigger", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (guessNum > number && trials != maxTrials - 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The number is smaller", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (trials == maxTrials) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You dont have more tries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The number was " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I think it's not counting the trials, because it's generating a random number every time the user inputs a guess. I've tried entering 17 and it shows a message that "the value is bigger" and I enter 18 and shows a message that "the value is smaller". It's as if it's not saving the random number.

Comment: I think your problem is with the for loop condition `trials < maxTrials`. So when `trails == maxTrails` it will not even enter the for loop. Try changing it to `trails <= maxTrails`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You do not have to break as that should be handled by the for loop -- @mkjh

This is already the reason that the for-loop is ending, so placing it afterward instead of as a test/break condition will be more efficient. Also,

> Try changing it to trials <= maxTrials – @viv3k

```
// start at trial 1 & end when trial == the max
for (trials = 1; trials <= maxTrials; trials++) 
{
    ...
}
// then after that loop
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You dont have more tries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The number was " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The break statement is provided by the test condition `trials < maxTrials` in the for-loop

**EDIT for additional info**

> once I input a number, the "the number is ..." message repeats three times, and shows that the user ran out of trials, but only one number has been input.

I can see that a value is being entered out of the loop

```java
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(num_input.getText().toString());
    int number = 1 + (int) (30 * Math.random());
```

Then inside of the loop, there is not another place to take a user's guess so it tests those conditions with the same number each time. Reading in the user's guess within the loop will allow you to reassign a value to test on the next loop around (edited the format into a while-loop)

```java
    trials = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    // under 3 guesses and not found
    while(++trials <= maxTrials && !found) 
    {
        // they guessed it
        if (guessNum == number) 
        {
            they win;
            found = true;
        } // they didn't guess it
        else 
        {
            if (guessNum < number)
                it is bigger;
            else
                it is smaller;
            // take the next guess when it is > or <
            guessNum = Integer.parseInt(num_input.getText().toString());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**NOTE** This is not full code

Comment: It did work! But now once I input a number, the "the number is ..." message repeats three times, and shows that the user ran out of trials, but only one number has been input.

Comment: @aurora -- I have included additional information

Answer (score 0):

`trials` will never be `==` to `maxTrials`. In your for loop, you are starting with `trials = 0` and stops the loop when `trials < maxTrials`. The criteria should be changed to `trials == maxTrials-1` instead. Also, you do not have to `break` as that should be handled by the for loop